# Perl: mocking -d -f and friends. How to put them into CORE::GLOBAL

Tags: perl, mocking

The CORE documentation has shown me how to merrily mock various built Perl functions. However, I'm not really sure how to replace '-d' &c. with my methods. So this is really just a question on how do i replace a function with a dash in it in CORE::GLOBAL.

A manual reference would be nice.

```
package Testing::MockDir;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter();
use Symbol 'qualify_to_ref';

*import = \&Exporter::import;

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(SetMockDir UnsetMockDir);

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'all' => \@EXPORT_OK,
);

my %path2List = ();
my %handle2List = ();

BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::opendir = \&Testing::MockDir::opendir;
    *CORE::GLOBAL::readdir = \&Testing::MockDir::readdir;
    *CORE::GLOBAL::closedir = \&Testing::MockDir::closedir;

    ######################### the "-" is really the problem here
    *CORE::GLOBAL::-d = \&Testing::MockDir::mock_d; # This does not work <<<<<
}

sub mock_d ($) {
    die 'It worked';
}

sub SetMockDir {
    my ($path, @files) = @_;
    $path2List{$path} = [@files];
}

sub UnsetMockDir {
    my ($path) = @_;
    delete $path2List{$path};
}

sub opendir (*$) {
    my $handle = qualify_to_ref(shift, caller);
    my ($path) = @_;
    return CORE::opendir($handle, $path) unless defined $path2List{$path};
    $handle2List{$handle} = $path2List{$path};
    return 1;
}

sub readdir (*) {
    my $handle = qualify_to_ref(shift, caller);
    return CORE::readdir($handle) unless defined $handle2List{$handle};
    return shift @{$handle2List{$handle}} unless wantarray;

    my @files = @{$handle2List{$handle}};
    $handle2List{$handle} = [];
    return @files;
}

sub closedir (*) {
    my $handle = qualify_to_ref(shift, caller);
    return CORE::closedir($handle) unless defined $handle2List{$handle};
    delete $handle2List{$handle};
    return 1;
}

1;
```

Comment: Why `*import = \&Exporter::import;` rather than `use Exporter 'import';`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may not be possible. The [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) section on [Overriding Built-in Functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions) is vague about which functions can be overridden. "Many" can, "some" can't, but aside from a handful of examples there's no definitive list.

Normally, I'd try this:

```
{
    no strict 'refs';
    *{'CORE::GLOBAL::-d'} = \&Testing::MockDir::mock_d;
}
```

which isn't a syntax error, but doesn't have the effect of overriding `-d`.

Comment: If that's the case then I'll have to make the target code more testable. thanks

Comment: Overriding CORE::GLOBAL has to happen at BEGIN time or Perl won't see it.  Its a performance hack.  Anyhow, CORE::GLOBAL only works with things with prototypes.  -d has no prototype.

Answer (score 13):

CORE::GLOBAL doesn't work on things without prototypes.  The only way I can think to do it is rewrite the opcode tree... which is not for the faint of heart.  You could pull it off with a combination of [B::Utils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B::Utils) and [B::Generate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B::Generate) and a lot of experimentation.

Simplest thing to do would be to use [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Temp) to make a temporary directory structure to your liking.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all for your answers.

What I wound up doing is, on a per module/test target basis, I factored out the code with the "-d" into it into it's own function. Like so...

```
# Because I cannot mock -d directly
sub dirExists {
    return -d shift;
}
```

Then I can replace this function in the test module with like

```
my $doesDirExist = 1;
*MyModule::dirExists   = \&main::mock_dirExists;

sub mock_dirExists {
    return $doesDirExist;
}
```

It's pretty ugly but i didn't want to get hung up on this too long and it works well enuf for my purposes

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your app is dependent on hard-coded file specifications.  You should parameterize the file specifications; then you don't have to mock anymore, you can just use Directory::Scratch or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the source filter route:

```
package Testing::MockDir;
use Filter::Simple;
FILTER {   s/\s+\-d (\S+)/ Testing::MockDir::filetest 'd',$1/g };
sub filetest {
  my ($test, $file) = @_;
  print "Mocking  -$test $file\n";
  return 1;
}
```

(This sample code isn't very robust. For example it won't translate `-d$dir` or `-d "dirname with spaces"`, but you can beef it up until it meets the needs of your target code).

Comment: That is an intriguing idea... source code transformations... very Lispish Thanks!