# How can I mock -f on an object in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking

I have a Perl object that has defined `use overload '""' => \&name;`
and a `name` method.

In my unit tests I have mocked this object, including the `name` method, but code like

```
if (-d $object)
```

still gives me `Use of uninitialized value in -d ...`. The mocked method is not being executed.

My mock code:

```
my $CMmock = Test::MockObject::Extends->new('MyClass');
$CMmock->mock('name', sub { print "TEST!\n";});      
$CMmock->mock('""', sub {print "TEST!\n";});
```

Other methods that I have mocked are working.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954529/perl-mocking-d-f-and-friends-how-to-put-them-into-coreglobal

Comment: Interesting question, but please phrase the question proper in terms of mocking a class with overloads.

Comment: Thanks mobrule, that link solved my problems. Pity I didn't find it when I searched.

Answer (score 0):

[Overly complicated answer involving string evals elided.]

`overload` keeps an idea of what overloads are in effect in a magic place.  Sometimes, especially with dynamically-generated classes, it fails to notice a change.  You can force it to pay attention by blessing a fresh object into the class.  You can immediately discard the object; the blessing event is what matters.  You don't even have to store the object anywhere.  The following works for me:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed);

my $o = Test::MockObject::Extends->new('MyClass')
        ->mock(name => sub { "Bah!" })
;
bless {} => blessed $o;

print "$o\n";
```

Comment: However, I'd like it noted that the overly complicated answer involving string evals was pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't work for me. I probably phrased the question poorly. The actual mocking worked for me except for "-f" and "-d" operators. From the question that 'mobrule' linked, it seems that those operators cannot be mocked, at all. 

I'll probably use a solution where I replace "-d"/"-f" with some IO::File operation and mock IO::File, or create a method like "isFile { shift -f; }" and mock that instead.