# Which Perl built-ins cannot be overridden in CORE::GLOBAL?

Tags: perl

The [Overriding Built-in Functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions) section of the perlsub documentation provides

> There is a second method that is sometimes applicable when you wish to override a built-in everywhere, without regard to namespace boundaries. This is achieved by importing a sub into the special namespace `CORE::GLOBAL::`.

and then gives a few examples. At the end, however, is

> Finally, some built-ins (*e.g.* `exists` or `grep`) can't be overridden.

What is the full list?

Comment: I'm glad you asked this because I was just about to ask myself since I have to write about this for a book. :)

Comment: @brian d foy I'll send you my bill.

Comment: And I'll pay in beer coupons redeemable at some Perl event. :) I was going to try to do this by brute force and just see where Perl complained. I still might do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any value that is negative in `toke.c` can be overridden; all others may not. You can look at the source code [here](http://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/blead/toke.c).

For example, let's look at [`waitpid`](http://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/blead/toke.c#L10396) on line 10,396:

```
    case 'w':
      if (name[1] == 'a' &&
          name[2] == 'i' &&
          name[3] == 't' &&
          name[4] == 'p' &&
          name[5] == 'i' &&
          name[6] == 'd')
      {                                       /* waitpid    */
        return -KEY_waitpid;
      }
```

Since `waitpid` is negative, it may be overridden. How about `grep`?

```
        case 'r':
          if (name[2] == 'e' &&
              name[3] == 'p')
          {                                   /* grep       */
            return KEY_grep;
          }
```

It's positive, so it cannot be overridden. That means that the following keywords cannot be overridden:

> `chop, defined, delete, do, dump, each, else, elsif, eval, exists, for, foreach, format, glob, goto, grep, if, keys, last, local, m, map, my, next, no, package, pop, pos, print, printf, prototype, push, q, qq, qw, qx, redo, return, s, scalar, shift, sort, splice, split, study, sub, tie, tied, tr, undef, unless, unshift, untie, until, use, while, y`

Comment: The link in the OP contains a specific example of mocking `glob`.

Comment: That example does it by exporting a `glob` symbol to the calling package, not replacing a symbol in `CORE::GLOBAL::`

Comment: There must be some additional magic: `chop` and `splice` can be mocked. I think `shift`, `unshift`, `push`, and `pop` can, too.

Comment: @friedo: it's even stranger than that. From what I can tell, you can set `*CORE::GLOBAL::glob`, and then `CORE::glob` will call the mocked function, too.

Answer (score 6):

The [`prototype`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/prototype.html) function will tell you if you can override a `CORE::` function.

Here is a hacked together attempt to get all the functions without having to type them:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "-|", "perldoc", "-u", "perlfunc" or die $!;
my %seen;
while (<$fh>) {
    next unless my ($func) = /=item ([a-z]\w+)/;
    next if $seen{$func}++;

    my $prototype = prototype "CORE::$func";

    print "$func is ", defined $prototype ? "overiddable with $prototype " :
        "not overiddable", "\n";
}
```

Comment: There is additional magic that allows `do`, `require`, and `glob` to be overridden. See `perlsub` for the what (if not the how and why).

Answer (score 4):

There was an earlier question on SO lamenting the difficulty of [mocking the filetest operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954529/perl-mocking-d-f-and-friends-how-to-put-them-into-coreglobal) (`-f`, `-d`, `-x`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The [`readline(HANDLE)`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#readline) function (and the equivalent `<HANDLE>` I/O operator) can be mocked, but its behavior of auto-assigning to `$_` when used like

```
while (<HANDLE>) { ...    # equivalent to   while (defined($_=readline(HANDLE)))
```

cannot be. See hobbs comment at [How can I still get automatic assignment to '$_' with a mocked 'readline' function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081767/). This means code like

```
while (<>) {       # implicitly sets $_
    do_something_with($_);
}
```

will probably break if you redefine `readline`.