# How can I still get automatic assignment to '$_' with a mocked 'readline' function?

Tags: perl

Perl has some special handling for the `readline` function (and the equivalent `<>` I/O operator) where it treats the expressions

```
while (<HANDLE>)
while (readline(HANDLE))
```

as equivalent to

```
while (defined($_ = <HANDLE>))
```

cf.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'f($_) while <>'
f($_) while defined($_ = <ARGV>);      <--- implicitly sets $_
-e syntax OK
```

But this automatic assignment doesn't seem to happen if you hijack the `readline` function:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'BEGIN {
> *CORE::GLOBAL::readline = sub { }
> }
> f($_) while <>'
sub BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::readline = sub {
    };
}
f($_) while readline(ARGV);            <--- doesn't set $_ !
-e syntax OK
```

Of course, this will make the custom `readline` function work incorrectly for a lot of legacy code. The output of this code is `"foo"` with the BEGIN block and `"bar"` without it, but I want it to be `"BAR"`.

```
use warnings;
BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::readline = \&uc_readline; }
sub uc_readline {
    my $line = CORE::readline(shift || *ARGV);
    return uc $line if defined $line;
    return;
}
($_, $bar) = ("foo\n", "bar\n");
open X, '<', \$bar;
while (<X>) {
  print $_;           # want and expect to see  "BAR\n"
}
```

What options do I have to hijack the `readline` function but still get the proper treatment of the `while (<...>)` idiom? It's not practical to explicitly convert everything to `while (defined($_=<...>))` in all the legacy code.

Comment: The cause here is that the code that does this transformation (`Perl_newLOOPOP`, opmini.c:5318) works on the optree and it's looking for an `OP_READLINE` -- but if `CORE::GLOBAL::readline` is defined when compiling there will be an `OP_ENTERSUB` in its place instead to call that sub, so the while-transform never happens. I'm not sure if that qualifies as a bug or not :)

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid it was something like that. If it's not a bug, at least it's underdocumented.

Comment: oops, looks like I waited too long to tell you that I sent it to perlbug -- because so did you. That's okay, you gave a test case :)

Comment: This also affects `readdir` as of version 5.12. (prior versions didn't do this for you) It would also affect `glob`, except that if you try, you instead get a deep recursion error.

Answer (score 6):

This is a fairly dirty hack using overloading to detect boolean context, but it seems to do the trick.  It certainly needs more testing than I have given it before using this solution in a production environment:

```
use warnings;
BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::readline = \&uc_readline; }
sub uc_readline {
    my $line = CORE::readline(shift || *ARGV);
    return Readline->new(uc $line) if defined $line;
    return;
}

{package Readline;
    sub new {shift; bless [@_]}
    use overload fallback => 1,
        'bool' => sub {defined($_ = $_[0][0])},  # set $_ in bool context
        '""'   => sub {$_[0][0]},
        '+0'   => sub {$_[0][0]};
}

my $bar;
($_, $bar) = ("foo\n", "bar\n");
open X, '<', \$bar;
while (<X>) {
  print $_;           # want and expect to see  "BAR\n"
}
```

which prints:

```
BAR
```

This will also make `if (<X>) {...}` set `$_`.  I don't know if there is a way to limit the magic to only `while` loops.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you left out the `defined` test in boolean context.  But that's easy to fix.

Comment: @cjm => what do you mean? `uc_readline` already includes a `defined` test before the overloading ever happens

Comment: If `$line` contains a defined-but-false value (like `'0'`), you assign it to `$_` and return it.  This will terminate the `while` loop.  You should return `defined $_` instead of `$_` in boolean context.

Comment: Or, since you've already arranged for Readline objects to be created only with a defined value, just skip the test and always return 1.

Comment: This doesn't localize $_, $_ is set to BAR after the while loop

Comment: @MkV => perl does not localize `$_` when set implicitly by a while loop.  if used in a subroutine, it is up to the author to localize `$_` before the loop.

Comment: Drat. This also sets `$_` when you say `while ($line=<X>)`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
use warnings;
BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::readline = \&uc_readline; }
sub uc_readline {
    my $line = CORE::readline(shift || *ARGV);
    return unless defined $line;
    $line = uc $line;
    $_ = $line;
    return $line;
}
($_, $bar) = ("foo\n", "bar\n");
open X, '<', \$bar;
while (<X>) {
  print $_;           # want and expect to see  "BAR\n"
}
print "$_";           # prints "BAR" instad of "foo"
```

does almost the right thing, but $_ is not localised, so after the loop,  $_ is set to the last value read from the filehandle.  Adding [Scope::Upper](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scope-Upper) to the mix fixes that:

```
use warnings;
use Scope::Upper qw/localize SCOPE/;
BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::readline = \&uc_readline; }
sub uc_readline {
    my $line = CORE::readline(shift || *ARGV);
    return unless defined $line;
    $line = uc $line;
    local $_ = $line;
    # localize $_ in the scope of the while
    localize *main::_, \$line, SCOPE(1);
    return $line;
}
($_, $bar) = ("foo\n", "bar\n");
open X, '<', \$bar;
while (<X>) {
  print "$_";           # want and expect to see  "BAR\n"
}
print "$_";             # will print 'foo', not "BAR"
```

Comment: But this also sets `$_` when you say `while ($line=<X>)`.