# Is there anything in core Perl to auto-chomp lines from "<>" operator?

Tags: perl, input

One of the minor annoyances I have when doing Perl coding is the necessity to remember to chomp a line that you read from input. Yeah, after years of coding it's nearly automatic to remember to do so, but STILL annoying.

Is there any pragma, module or anything else in Perl (strongly preferred Core modules) that automatically chomps every line read using a `<>` operator?

Comment: Just to be clrear - I'd prefer something that's NOT a hack. E.g. source filters are not something I would consider a good answer.

Comment: You can always use the `-l` switch. Placed in the shebang, it should work.

Comment: @TLP - does it work without `-n`/`-p`? perlrun says "First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. "

Comment: Nope, it actually adds an `$\\` to the output

Comment: @SinanÜnür It does not add `$\ `, because that is automatically added at the end of print statements if it is defined. The `-l` switch simply sets `$\ ` and `$/` to `\n`. DVK, you may be right that it does not chomp without the `-n/-p` switches.

Comment: @TLP I did not phrase that correctly. Thanks for catching that, and correcting my mistake.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081767 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5084781/55857

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beyond the asquerous source filters that  you already mentioned, I’m afraid I don’t know what counts as  “a hack” for your purposes here.   Do you consider any of these obviousish solutions to be “hacks”?

1. overriding `*CORE::readline` in the current package
2. overriding  `*CORE::GLOBAL::readline` in all packages
3. handle ties to a class with a custom `READLINE` method
4. operator overloading of the `<>` operator

Have you tried those yet?

Of those, I would think the first, or possibly the second, to be the most likely to do what you want with the least amount of fuss.

Note that all four of those solutions require nothing but pure Perl and nothing else. They do  not even require any core modules, let alone any  CPAN modules.

Comment: #1/2 = NOT a hack. As a matter of fact, pretty much what I was looking for. Though #2 is not all that obvious - need to do it so that it applies to ALL packages, current and future. I'm thinking an override of "require" would have to happen for that.

Comment: #1/2 [have their own idiosyncracies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081767). If you don't like saying `chomp`, you probably won't like saying `defined($_=<>)`, either :-(

Comment: #3/4 probably have the same problem.

Comment: @mob - could you please elaborate for #1/2? I thought readline is the implementation of `<>`?

Comment: @DVK - check out the link. Usually `while(<>)` means `while(defined($_=<>))`. There's a bug that if you override `readline`, this is no longer true.

Comment: @mob - sorry, didn't notice the link in the comment. You're absolutely right

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you already know this, but when you combine the command line options `-nl` together you get the behavior you want (assuming you want the implicit `while(<>)` loop:

```
$ perl -nle 'printf q{%s}, $_'
```

Usually the two options are used to run a short perl command via bash command line, but I guess nothing prevents you from doing it in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nl

# puts the newline back on if you use print:
# print

# does not put the newline back on
printf '%s', $_;
```

Brief description of this behavior here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=324749

Comment: Works but I really do not understand why!

Comment: @MUYBelgium Check `perldoc perlrun`, it has this (among other things) to say about the option: "it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p". The value of `$/` defaults to the newline, so that means that using `-l` implies that newlines are stripped from input. However, `-l` also sets `$\` to `$/`, so all `print` statements will end in a new line. To solve that problem, `printf` is used instead of `print`. However, the answer here has a rather critical bug, and that is that it corrupts output when `%` is present in the input stream. Fix: `printf q{%s}, $_`