# Is there a less tedious way to use Perl chomp?

Tags: perl

Very frequently I have to do:

```
#similarly in while (my $val = <$fh>){...}
my $val = <$fh>;
chomp $val;

my $res = `command`;
chomp $res;
```

I'd rather skip the second line if I could.  I see I can use the -l option in my shebang line based on:  [Is there anything in core Perl to auto-chomp lines from "<>" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154783/is-there-anything-in-core-perl-to-auto-chomp-lines-from-operator)

Is there something similar for backticks?  Or alternately, is there a way to chomp inline that is less verbose?

Comment: it is not a bad thing to have code that does what it says.

Comment: @ysth of course, and I wouldn't accept a solution that isn't that way.  I wasn't too fond of the "-l" option put in the shebang line because it's easy to miss.  I don't like using two lines, and I don't want to do `my $x = <>; chomp $x;` in one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sub chomper(_) {
   my ($line) = @_;
   chomp($line) if defined($line);
   return $line;
}

while (defined( my $line = chomper(<>) )) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could see this being useful in a common lib.  I understand you need this scalar implementation when calling chomper on a <HANDLE> to not slurp up all lines at once.  Otherwise maybe this variant can be used for both scalars and arrays  `sub chomper {
   chomp(@_) if defined(@_);
   return @_;
}
`

Comment: `defined(@array)` makes no sense. And your changes make it unusable to the OP (without adding `scalar` around the argument in the caller)

Comment: I understand the OP is for scalar context.  I'm trying to see if both scalars and arrays can be handled as native chomp can, i.e. something that would allow `my @files = chomper(\`ls\`);`

Comment: I just said you could... but I take it back. It would make for a really weird sub. Best to make it only work on a scalar, and use `map` to apply it to each element of a list. (`my @files = map chomper, \`ls\``)

Comment: About `_` I found the following (learned a new thing):  "As the last character of a prototype, or just before a semicolon, a @ or a % , you can use _ in place of $ : if this argument is not provided, $_ will be used instead."    I'm still unclear on why we need the `if defined` condition.

Comment: @Automaton, Because `<>` returns undef on EOF.

Comment: I understand but I didn't see any issue when removing that condition, at least not in my perl-5.10 release.  I even tried `$my u = chomper(undef); print ">$u<";` and it gives `><` without complaining.

Comment: That code isn't valid Perl, so I'm pretty sure it did complain. Even if you fix the typo, you'd get not one but two "uninitialized value" warnings

Comment: silly mistake on my part of forgetting to use strict & warnings, that's why it didn't complain.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap `chomp` around the whole expression

```
chomp(my $date = `date`);
say $date;
```

For other suggestions on a sort of "auto-chomp" on filehandles, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10155406/3124587) answer.

**Update**: There's also a [`Backtick::AutoChomp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Backtick::AutoChomp) module, which is implemented with a source filter.

**EDIT**

I originally also had the following snippet without actually testing it

```
while (chomp(my $line = <$fh>)) {
    say $line;
}
```

As per ikegami's comment, this is unreliable and will misbehave in various ways.

Comment: Bad! This solution throws a warning if the last line ends with a line feed or if the file is empty, and it skips the last line otherwise.

Comment: Also -1 for suggesting a source filter as a solution to any problem

Comment: I specifically mentioned it uses a source filter so the reader can make their own decision on whether they're ok with that. If it makes it any better, the source filter is parsed using `PPI`, which makes it some-what more reliable, but of course not perfect.

Comment: I could use this part: `chomp(my $date = \`date\`);`  I had tried something close before posting this and it failed with "Can't modify scalar chomp in scalar assignment" - that's because I missed adding the parens.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to reduce tedium is to learn to love `$_`

```
while(<$fh>) {
   chomp;
}

local $_ = <$fh>;
chomp;

local $_ = `command`;
chomp;
```

Same number of lines, but now they are half as long :)

edit: Corrected thanks to @ysth's comment, learnt something new today

Comment: `<$fh>;` throws away a line; it only implicitly sets `$_` in a while expression

Comment: While this is nice for short programs, be wary: $_ is a global variable, and code you call can easily clobber it in the middle of your loop; also, while(<$fh>) does *not* localize its usage of $_, and so will inflict the same on any outer code. Assigning to a lexical variable avoids both these problems.