# What is the difference between "while(<FH>)" and "if(<FH>)" in perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

This works :-

```
while (<CONF>) {
  print $_;
}
```

but this doesn't :-

```
if (<CONF>) {
  print $_;
}
```

and gives an error about uninitialized values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well: "Which [is your favorite] value?" That is the start of your quest. Don't get tossed off a bridge.

Comment: I ask this because the real question is more like: "What magic behind while(<FH>) gives $_ meaningful values?" I would start by looking in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) (for `while`) and, if that fails, [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (for `$_`).

Comment: The docs you seek are in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)

Comment: Sort of related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081767/. Eric Strom demonstrates a hack that will get `if (<HANDLE>)` (and `unless <HANDLE>` and `until <HANDLE>`) to auto assign to `$_`, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (<CONF>)
```

gets rewritten to

```
while (defined($_ = <CONF>))
```

so you probably want

```
if (defined($_ = <CONF>))
```

Answer (score 4):

I/O from a filehandle is read to $_ only when it is the sole condition in a while loop.  This is a special case.  It won't read into $_ in an if.  See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap.html#Perl-Traps)