# Perl - New definition of myprint() or Overload print command

Tags: perl, printing

I am a newb to Perl. I am writing some scripts and want to define my own print called `myprint()` which will print the stuff passed to it based on some flags (verbose/debug flag)

```
open(FD, "> /tmp/abc.txt") or die "Cannot create abc.txt file";
print FD "---Production Data---\n";
myprint "Hello - This is only a comment - debug data";
```

Can someone please help me with some sample code to for `myprint()` function?

Comment: First the language is called Perl or perl ... not PERL. And you might want to look at `Log::Log4perl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you care more about writing your own logging system, or do you want to know how to put logging statements in appropriate parts of your program which you can turn off (and, incur little performance penalty when they are turned off)?

If you want a logging system that is easy to start using, but also offers a world of features which you can incrementally discover and use, [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Log::Log4perl) is a good option. It has an easy mode, which allows you to specify the desired logging level, and emits only those logging messages that are above the desired level.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use File::Temp qw(tempfile);
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

Log::Log4perl->easy_init({level => $INFO});

my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile;

print $fh "---Production Data---\n";

WARN 'Wrote something somewhere somehow';
```

The snippet also shows a better way of opening a temporary file using [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Temp).

As for overriding the built-in [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) … It really isn't a good idea to fiddle with built-ins except in very specific circumstances. `perldoc perlsub` has a section on [Overriding Built-in Functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions). The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678882/which-perl-built-ins-cannot-be-overridden-in-coreglobal) lists the [Perl built-ins that cannot be overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678882/which-perl-built-ins-cannot-be-overridden-in-coreglobal). `print` is one of those.

But, then, one really does not need to override a built-in to write a logging system.

So, if an already-written logging system does not do it for you, you really seem to be asking "how do I write a function that prints stuff conditionally depending on the value of a flag?"

Here is one way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package My::Logger;
{
    use strict; use warnings;
    use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
        exports => [
            DEBUG => sub {
                return sub {} unless $ENV{MYDEBUG};
                return sub { print 'DEBUG: ' => @_ };
            },
        ]
    };
}

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

# You'd replace this with use My::Logger qw(DEBUG) if you put My::Logger
# in My/Logger.pm somewhere in your @INC
BEGIN {
    My::Logger->import('DEBUG');
}

sub nicefunc {
    print "Hello World!\n";
    DEBUG("Isn't this a nice function?\n");
    return;
}

nicefunc();
```

Sample usage:

```
$ ./yy.pl
Hello World!
$ MYDEBUG=1 ./yy.pl
Hello World!
DEBUG: Isn't this a nice function?
```

Comment: What Sinan hasn't said is that Log4perl lets you write the logging statements in the program but then decide in configuration if those logging statements do anything. I have a chapter on this in _Mastering Perl_.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't going to answer this because Sinan already has the answer I'd recommend, but tonight I also happened to be working on the "Filehandle References" chapter to the upcoming [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com). That are a couple of relevant paragraphs which I'll just copy directly without adapting them to your question:

---

**IO::Null and IO::Interactive**

Sometimes we don't want to send our output anywhere, but we are forced
to send it somewhere. In that case, we can use IO::Null to create 
a filehandle that simply discards anything that we give it. It looks 
and acts just like a filehandle, but does nothing:

```
use IO::Null;

my $null_fh = IO::Null->new;

some_printing_thing( $null_fh, @args );
```

Other times, we want output in some cases but not in others. If we are
logged in and running our program in our terminal, we probably want to 
see lots of output. However, if we schedule the job through *cron*, we
probably don't care so much about the output as long as it does the job.
The IO::Interactive module is smart enough to tell the difference:

```
use IO::Interactive;

print { is_interactive } 'Bamboo car frame';
```

The `is_interactive` subroutine returns a filehandle. Since the
call to the subroutine is not a simple scalar variable, we surround
it with braces to tell Perl that it's the filehandle.

Now that you know about "do nothing" filehandles, you can replace some
ugly code that everyone tends to write. In some cases you want output
and in some cases you don't, so many people use a post-expression
conditional to turn off a statement in some cases:

```
print STDOUT "Hey, the radio's not working!" if $Debug;
```

Instead of that, you can assign different values to `$debug_fh` based
on whatever condition you want, then leave off the ugly `if $Debug`
at the end of every `print`:

```
use IO::Null;

my $debug_fh = $Debug ? *STDOUT : IO::Null->new;

$debug_fh->print( "Hey, the radio's not working!" );
```

The magic behind IO::Null might give a warning about "print() on
unopened filehandle GLOB" with the indirect object notation (e.g.
`print $debug_fh`) even though it works just fine. We don't get that
warning with the direct form.