# Is there a debugging tool like Firebug for server-side Perl/CGI?

Tags: perl, debugging, testing, cgi

I really enjoy using Firebug for debugging my JavaScript code, HTML DOM, and network loading, that is: everything client-side about web development.

The situation is not so bright on the server side. The application which I'm working on uses Perl with the obligatory standard modules like [CGI](http://metacpan.org/module/CGI) and [DBI](http://metacpan.org/module/DBI). I know the [standard troubleshooting techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script), but there seems to be no debugging tool that traces e.g. database queries or function calls and gives me nice output.

The output must especially not just be yanked on STDOUT (imagine `Content-Type: application/json`) or STDERR (grepping through error logs is quite uncomfortable), and the tool should not require me to manually monkey-patch stuff into core modules or sprinkle `use Data::Dumper; print '<pre>',Dumper($foo),'</pre>'` through-out the code.

**Long story short:** Is there a tool that makes debugging the server-side of Perl/CGI as fun as Firebug does on the client-side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there are, but they rely on [Plack](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack).  Plack is a layer which sits between web frameworks and web servers.  Plack smooths over server differences and offers a place to [plug in all sorts of debugging tools](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aMiddleware%3a%3aDebug).  These include database [profile](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aMiddleware%3a%3aDebug%3a%3aDBIProfile) and [trace](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aMiddleware%3a%3aDebug%3a%3aDBITrace) information, and you can [write your own debugging panels](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aMiddleware%3a%3aDebug#HOW-TO-WRITE-YOUR-OWN-DEBUG-PANEL).  There is also an [interactive debugger](http://blogs.perl.org/users/yko/2011/07/hello-world-in-plack-2-interactive-debugger.html), though I haven't used it myself.

Many Perl web frameworks these days (Catalyst and Dancer for example) use Plack, but if you're using straight Perl and CGI you're not going to get it.  Fortunately, it's pretty easy to make a CGI application run on Plack.  Either [replace CGI with a subclass that uses Plack](http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-6-convert-cgi-apps-to-psgi.html), or [wrap your CGI code in an emulation layer](http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-9-running-cgi-scripts-on-plack.html).

Converting to Plack has a lot of advantages beyond the debugging tools, it's well worth the effort.

Comment: +1, because PSGI/Plack is the modern way. And I really like [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/module/Enbugger) which allows the loading of the debugger at runtime.

Comment: Plack::Middleware::Debug looks nice, but still hsa the problem that it works only with `Content-Type: text/html` since it manipulates "STDOUT".

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Yeah, you'd have to temporarily change the content type. Otherwise it would have to be a browser plugin, and I don't know of any to debug server-side code.

Answer (score 6):

No, not really.

Things you can do are:

Sprinkle your code with debug code.

```
use constant DEBUG => 1;
...;
debug_function($var) if DEBUG;
```

Once you unset the `DEBUG` constant for deployment, you won't have any extra runtime costs (the statements are optimized away), and you can re-activate them whenever neccessary.

You can even say evil things like

```
BEGIN {require Data::Dumper if DEBUG}
```

to conditionally load debugging modules.

If you want to override Core functions, why not add debug handlers? That's not evil patching, thats augmenting…

```
BEGIN {
   if (DEBUG) {
      my $oldfunction = \&CORE::function;
      *CORE::function = sub {  # add prototypes if you like them
         debug_handler(@_);
         &$oldfunction;
      };
   }
}
```

Use this technique to log your calls to your database.

You can re-open `STDERR` to some special file (or pipe, or terminal, or…)

```
BEGIN {
   if (DEBUG) {
      close STDERR or die "STDERR hates me and doesn't want to be closed.";
      open STDERR, '>', "/path/to/my/error/log.file" or die "couldn't open error log";
   }
}
```

You can define your `DIE` and `WARN` handlers to do something *you* want:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    print MYERRORS "There was a warning: $!";
    # do additional error handling unless you're paranoid
}
```

The `warnings` pragma can help you to make important warnings fatal:

```
use warnings qw(FATAL importantWarning);
```

or to create your own warnings, just see the documentation

And to get call stack traces, look into the numerous possibilities of the `caller` function. Essentially, you might want to build your personal interpretation of the `Carp` module as `CGI::Carp` may not meet your needs.

Comment: Correction: `print` cannot be overridden. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3678957/334761

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Thankyou for that tip, I made my example generic.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, check [Devel::LTrace](http://search.cpan.org/~koorchik/Debug-LTrace-0.03/lib/Debug/LTrace.pm#VERSION), which can tell you when named subroutines are called, and [Devel::CallTrace](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/Devel-CallTrace-1.2/lib/Devel/CallTrace.pm), which can tell what you what subroutines are called when and where.