# Overriding the "eval" in perl

Tags: perl

Having the following:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    use subs qw(int);
    sub int {
        print STDERR "\tthe int got: $_[0]\n";
        my $res =  CORE::int($_[0]);
        print STDERR "\tCORE::int: $res\n";
        return $res;
    }
}

my $x;
$x = 1.1 ; say "result of int($x) is: ", int($x);
$x = 6.6 ; say "result of int($x) is: ", int($x);
```

it prints

```
    the int got: 1.1
    CORE::int: 1
result of int(1.1) is: 1
    the int got: 6.6
    CORE::int: 6
result of int(6.6) is: 6
```

The `int` function is overridden by my own function, which does some debug-prints, and returns the result of the original (CORE) implementation.

Looking for the same for the `eval`. But, probably because the `eval` isn't a function like the `int` the override as above doesn't works for the eval.

Is it possible to achieve this somewhat? E.g. want override the `eval` (the `eval "$string"`) with my own eval as above, e.g.:

- should print the got string
- and should call the core implementation of the eval

EDIT:
According to comments the above isn't possible for the `eval`. So:

*In short: want debug print of **all** `eval "$strings"` in my program, before evaluation. It is possible somewhat?*

Comment: At least accoring to http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html it would appear that `eval` doesn't exist as `CORE::eval`, which I believe means it is a Perl keyword that lacks a means of being overridden.

Comment: @DavidO Corroborated by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3678957/176646) to a related question.

Comment: [`overload::eval`](https://metacpan.org/pod/overload::eval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval` can't be overridden in the same fashion as `int` since its interface can't be prototyped.

```
$ perl -E'say prototype("CORE::".$ARGV[0]) // "[undef]"' int
_

$ perl -E'say prototype("CORE::".$ARGV[0]) // "[undef]"' eval
[undef]
```

But there's some good news! Someone had similar needs to yours, solved it by manipulating the opcode, and published a solution to CPAN in the form of [overload::eval](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload::eval) for everyone to use.

The documentation claims to only affect `eval` in the lexical scope of the `use`, but there's a hidden flag `$overload::eval::GLOBAL = 1;` that makes it affect all calls to `eval EXPR`.

Comment: Thank you pointing me to `overload::eval`, unfortunately it doesn't instal cleanly (failed tests) in the OSX/perl-v5.22.