# Mock filesystem for Perl unit testing

Tags: perl, unit-testing, filesystems, mocking

Is there a method or module that allows me to simulate a fake filesystem for use with Perl unit testing?

I use a variety of `Test::*` and `Test::Mock*` modules in my unit testing, but occasionally I'd like to be able to fake a filesystem.  A simple example (and a minimum requirement) would be faking the result from the `-r` or `-f` file test operators, so that when I call objects or modules that perform file tests, I can more easily control the result.

I know that there are all manner of ways of getting around this problem, such as creating temporary files or wrapping file tests in their own functions which can then be mocked, but sometimes it would be nice if I could just get Perl to lie to me...  So solutions that suggest rewriting the code being tested are not required ;-)

**Update:**

After having just found and read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954529/perl-mocking-d-f-and-friends-how-to-put-them-into-coreglobal), rewriting the code so that it is more testable is looking like the more sensible option.  Still, fingers crossed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are worth a look: [Filesys::Virtual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys::Virtual) and
[Filesys::Virtual::Async](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys::Virtual::Async). I’ve used the first. Mixed with [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class) and [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Temp) it is easy to do all kinds of self-cleaning things tersely and elegantly. [Test::Virtual::Filesystem](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Virtual::Filesystem) also looks interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I confess to being unsure what I would do with Filesys::Virtual - it appears to be a base class for something else. Please could you expand a little upon how you have used it in the past?

Comment: @Mike, sorry, I really should have linked this one: [Filesys::Virtual::Plain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys::Virtual::Plain). It's much closer to ready to use out of the box.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up finding that too, and it looks like a good possibility.  I've not had chance to check it out yet, but hope to do so soon.

Comment: Test::Virtual::Filesystem is a module for writing tests for virtual filesystem itself.